# How do I get variables from a returned value within a function of a function?

Tags: python

I would like to put the returned player who sent the message `!player1` or `!player2` into a short list so that I can them for later, but I can't seem to find out how to get returned variables from functions inside of functions. I saw something about Closure which I think this is but even following the example I can't seem to get the returned values so I can assign them.

```
    def players(sender, event):

    def getplayer():

        msg = event.parsed[0]['msg']

        if msg == '!player1':
            BotBasicFunction.sendmsg(msgg='{} has joined the game!'.format(hasplayer()))
            hasplayer()

        if msg == '!player2':
            BotBasicFunction.sendmsg(msgg='{} has joined the game!'.format(hasplayer()))
            hasplayer()

    def hasplayer():
        invoker = event.parsed[0]['invokername']
        return invoker

    parsedmsg = event.parsed[0]['msg']

    players = [getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer()]

    if parsedmsg == '!players':
        BotBasicFunction.sendmsg(msgg='{}'.format(players))
```

Comment: You don't always seem to be saving references to hold on to the returned values, e.g. `my_reference = getplayer()`, `my_other_reference = hasplayer()`.

Comment: `return a` and `return b` ? ..Return what?

Comment: did you mean `a = hasplayer()` instead of just `hasplayer()`?

Comment: Yes I have this in my code now but how am I suppose to get who they are as players when the `getplayer()` is just for getting who sent the message?

Comment: agreeing with @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور, what do you think `a` and `b` are on the lines where you are returning them?

Comment: also instead of creating four separate player variables, then creating an empty list, then extending the list by a tuple of players, you could just as well have `players = [getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer()]`

Comment: I thought it would Return it as `a` and `b` if I did that, so leaving it blank will still leave the same thing right?

Comment: Using `players = [getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer(), getplayer()]` doesn't work because it will print the same value each time. That's why I tried assigning each `getplayer()` as a different variable inside so I could use it outside.

Comment: Is getplayer() supposed to nested inside players()?

Comment: This is just the way I happened to do it since it follows the same way I do a similar function in my actual code. Is it bad that I do this?